# How to get external data without CORS headers with Firebase hosted webapp?

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, cors, firebase-hosting

I have my Ionic2 app hosted on Firebase. What I need is to get external data from an API service where

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource

I can work around it locally by using proxies in **ionic.config.json** file:

```
"proxies": [
{
"path":"/api",
"proxyUrl": "https://api.somwhere.com/"
}
]
```

But I have no idea how to deal with this after deploying my app to Firebase. Is it somehow possible?

Comment: Not familiar with Firebase but basically, CORS is a browser-implemented solution to a browser-implemented restriction on ajax requests. So, the only alternative is to avoid the cross domain requests by proxying (or having the server do the request instead, which is basically the same type of workaround). You should do some research into proxying options allowed by Firebase.

Comment: Any luck solving this? I have a feeling the change needs to take place where the API service is hosted.. but what if we can't access or change that?

Comment: No luck, I use https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ for now.

Answer (score 5):

The [Firebase docs have an example of setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#headers) in your `firebase.json` to allow cross-origin requests for font files. You could adjust that like this:

```
"headers": [ {
  "source" : "**",
  "headers" : [ {
    "key" : "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
    "value" : "*"
  } ]
}
```

That will allow cross-origin requests for all resources. Of course if you want to restrict it to specific resources, you can adjust the `source` value.

Comment: Do we need to let cache expire before this will work. This is my firebase.json and I still get CORS error.

{
 "hosting": {
  "public": "./src/empty",
  "headers": [ {
   "source" : "**",
   "headers" : [ {
   "key" : "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
   "value" : "*"
   } ]
  } ]
 }
}

Comment: Note that the CORS error ("from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.") is while trying to access and image off firebase storage not in the folder hosted

Comment: You do need to wait for the cache expire, yeah. Either that or if you can, get the browser to force (re)load the resources. But that doesn’t necessarily work for getting around intermediate network caches/proxies

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out how to cache images from Firebase Storage. I need to get the images using Ajax to get the resource but I get the CORS error listed above

Comment: @Xerri Sounds like you probably want to post a separate new question about that

Comment: I did but no luck

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not a firebase related issue. Your api needs to send CORS in header. Either accept all(*) or your specific firebase hosted app.
Easy fix for API written in .net 
See link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Answer (score 0):

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
 adding on server htaccess file solve my problem